# Environment Variable for debugging in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, environment-variables, visual-studio-2022

I have a problem in Environment Variable in Visual studio 2022. When I use Development there is no problem and it takes development AppSettings,

[image: Environment_Variable_Development]

But when I remove Environment variable to use production (Default AppSettings) it brings me Error and It doesn't run.

[image: Environment_Variable_Empty]

What should I do to use default AppSetting in debug mode?

the error is 404 not found :

[image: Not_Found_Error]

Comment: Have you tried remove the whole string i.e. instead of having ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT= just leave the box empty?

Comment: Yes I did, but it brings error and doesn't work. @SimplyGed

Comment: Can you add the error to the question please?

Comment: Yes, of course. @SimplyGed

Comment: Did you try `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=production`?

Comment: Yes, While there is not exist AppSettings.Production.json, it brings 404 @Fabio

Comment: Where do you use your swagger Middleware? Is it in the `if app.Environment.IsDevelopment())` statement? If so, it will only show when you are running in development.

Comment: After searching about 3 hour I find out what you told exactly and because of default code generation, I have forgotten to check that. @klekmek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using swagger check the swagger middlware. it should be out of development environment, just modify this line of code in program.cs:

```
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
```

to this:

```
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
}
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();
```